# axis label with different string with different x(or y) range

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 900X900 2-d numpy array that I plotted using the matshow() method, the result is great but I don't want to show the position of the pixel on the axis, rather, I want to label the x-axis and y-axis with different strings at specified locations(eg. x=50, x=200, x=700 ,y=50, y=200, y=700). I also want to only show x and y ticks at specified locations(eg.x=100, x=400, and x=900). So, how to do it?
This is my sample code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

two_d_array_900 = np.random.rand(900,900)
print(two_d_array_900)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111) 
color_map = plt.cm.get_cmap('PiYG')
max_value = np.nanmax(two_d_array_900)
min_value = np.nanmin(two_d_array_900)
middle_value = (max_value+min_value)/2
norm_thresholded = cm.colors.DivergingNorm(vmax = max_value, 
vcenter=middle_value,vmin=min_value)
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax_for_colbar= divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
im = ax.matshow(two_d_array_900, cmap=color_map, norm=norm_thresholded)
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax_for_colbar)
ax.set_title("test", fontsize=15, y=1, pad=10)
```

This is the original figure [image: This is the original figure]
This is the desired figure[image: This is the desired figure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the major ticks and their labels to place the texts at the desired positions.
And use the minor ticks to mark the divisions. You might want to increase the padding for the title.

For example:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter

two_d_array_900 = gaussian_filter(np.random.randn(900, 900), 20)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
color_map = plt.cm.get_cmap('PiYG')
max_value = np.nanmax(two_d_array_900)
min_value = np.nanmin(two_d_array_900)
middle_value = (max_value + min_value) / 2
norm_thresholded = cm.colors.DivergingNorm(vmax=max_value, vcenter=middle_value, vmin=min_value)
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax_for_colbar = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.05)
im = ax.matshow(two_d_array_900, cmap=color_map, norm=norm_thresholded)
fig.colorbar(im, cax=cax_for_colbar)
ax.set_xticks([50, 200, 700])
ax.set_xticklabels(['A', 'B', 'C'], size=16)
ax.set_xticks([0, 100, 400, 900], minor=True)
ax.set_yticks([50, 200, 700])
ax.set_yticklabels(['A', 'B', 'C'], size=16)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', pad=10)
ax.set_yticks([0, 100, 400, 900], minor=True)
ax.tick_params(which='minor', length=25, bottom=False, right=False)
ax.tick_params(which='major', length=0)
ax.set_title("test", fontsize=15, y=1, pad=30)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Thanks for your help and very nice picture!! Really enjoy it!!